# Open session in view with annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, open-session-in-view

Is it possible to use an annotation to do whatever OpenSessionInView filter does:  to keep hibernate session open in scope but for only one annotated function?

PS I would need this for local fixes in some legacy code.

Comment: if you use spring you can do this with spring aop or use java proxy for open session ,  or you can use aspectj

Comment: I hope I won't need this but just in case I can't find something better: how?

Comment: what do you use except java ,  hibernate ? spring ?

Comment: all of them yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934397/configuring-hibernate-session-with-spring-aop?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: First thing that this is the looong path, of (re)building parts of hibernate which I try to avoid. secondly you showed how to create a pointcut (I already know that) but the main problem is what do I call afterwards? how do I keep session open and avoid closing it when not needed. So ...

Comment: You have session till you have transaction. Use it. Aspect is the shortest way if you what small changes for your source code

Comment: Also did you see this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInterceptor.html