# JoinPoint to match EntityManager methods

Tags: spring, spring-aop, entitymanager

I am trying to intercept calls to the **find** method in **EntityManager**.

```
public Map<String, String> get() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        DleTestData data = em.find(DleTestData.class, "1");
        map.put(data.getId(), data.getName() + " : " + data.getRegion());
        return map;
    }
```

I have an advice written like this:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class MyAdvice {

    @Around("execution(* javax.persistence.EntityManager.*(..))")
    public Object aroundFind(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.err.println("before em find called : " + joinPoint);
        Object o = null;
        try {

            o = joinPoint.proceed();

            System.err.println("after em find advice called : " + joinPoint);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return o;

    }

}
```

The output show calls intercepted but the **find** method doesn't get matched in the pointcut.
Can you suggest what am I doing wrong here?

output:

> before em find called : execution(Metamodel
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.getMetamodel()) after em find advice
>   called : execution(Metamodel
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.getMetamodel())

Answer (score 2):

The Spring AOP manual states that [Spring AOP only works for Spring beans/components](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn).

The same manual also describes how you can apply AOP to non-Spring classes via full [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). It is pretty easy to configure.

If you experience any problems weaving into a basic class from the `javax..*` package because maybe the class is loaded before LTW is activated (even though you should be able to do that if you use `javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`), you can still switch from `execution()` to `call()` pointcut. As long as the calls are in your own application code it should be easy to intercept via AspectJ. But you do need AspectJ for it, not Spring AOP, because the latter neither supports non-Spring beans (as mentioned above) nor `call()` pointcut (as mentioned in the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)).

---

**Update after OP's comment:**

I just checked the [`EntityManager` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) for you: Method `getMetaModel()` is part of the interface while `get()` is not. Consequently, the pointcut fails to find it.

Comment: By that logic...the question is that the calls to getMetaModel() which is defined in the same interference as find() and also has the same implementation class as find gets intercepted but the same doesn't work for find(). Also when u say LTW, you mean using @Configurable ? Of course xml driven here as the class.is a framework class. Isnthere a way I could do this easily with SpringBoot?

Comment: Thanks you for the efforts kriegaex. however, i just checked and foundteh find() method very much in the same javadocs link as you shared,         
   <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey)
Find by primary key.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you wanted to intercept the `get()` method you showed in your question. I overread that `find(..)` is your problematic case. Anyway, I cannot see which class `get(..)` belongs to and if that class is a Spring bean. Would you please edit your question and provide a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can stop guessing and start reproducing and analysing your problem? Extract a minimal example, buildable and compilable, optimally with Maven POM and cloneable from GitHub. You could have so many problems, I am getting tired of guessing just now.

Comment: I found another question here and I don't even see an answer for this so it seems this has more to do than mistakes in my configuration.:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934397/configuring-hibernate-session-with-spring-aop

Comment: i will extract and upload a minimal example, but for now I am using a workaround from the link above.