# JPQL query transformation doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I'm working in a query transformation sql -->JPQL, I use a eclipselink JPA framework.

Sql query return results correctly but JPQL query doesn't return anytthing, If any guy can give a clue will be greatfull.

JPA Entities:

```
/**
 * Contiene el mapeo de la siguiente entidad: <br/>
 * PRD_OWNER.BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS <br/>
 * Nombre                      Nulo     Tipo <br/>           
 *--------------------------- -------- --------------<br/> 
 * <b>LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER   </b>      <br/>
 * CREATION_DATE               NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)   <br/>
 * CREATED_BY                  NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * LAST_UPDATE_DATE            NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)   <br/>
 * LAST_UPDATED_BY             NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * LABEL_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * COLLECTION_ID               NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * SAMPLE                               NUMBER(1)      <br/>
 * COMMENTS                             VARCHAR2(4000) <br/>
 * RELATED_LABEL_COLLECTION_ID          NUMBER         <br/>
 * RELATED_SEASON_ID                    NUMBER         <br/>
 * ACTIVE                               NUMBER(1)      <br/>
 * FILE_SUPPLIER                        BLOB           <br/>
 * FILE_SUPPLIER_CONTENT_TYPE           VARCHAR2(25)   <br/>
 *
 * <b>permite vincular un etiqueta {@link Label} - coleccion {@link Collection} - temporada {@link ActivatableSeason}</b>
 * contiene objetos heredados de {@link BaseEntity} --> información de auditoria 
 */
//@formatter:on.
@Entity
@Table(name = "BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = LabelCollection.RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION, query = "SELECT labelCollection from LabelCollection labelCollection INNER JOIN labelCollection.label.seasonList season WHERE labelCollection.active=1 AND season.seasonId = :seasonId AND labelCollection.collection.collectionId = :collectionId ORDER BY labelCollection.sample DESC, labelCollection.label.referencia ASC"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelCollection.RETRIEVE_BY_CODE, query = "SELECT labelColecction FROM LabelCollection labelColecction WHERE labelColecction.active=1 AND labelColecction.label.referencia LIKE UPPER(:labelCode)"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelCollection.RETRIEVE_SAMPLE_LABELS_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION, query = "SELECT labelColecction from LabelCollection labelColecction INNER JOIN labelColecction.label.seasonList season WHERE labelColecction.active=1 AND labelColecction.sample = true AND season.seasonId = :seasonId AND labelColecction.collection.collectionId = :collectionId"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelCollection.RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION_LABEL_CODE, query = "SELECT labelCollection from LabelCollection labelCollection INNER JOIN labelCollection.label.seasonList season WHERE labelCollection.active=1 AND season.seasonId = :seasonId AND labelCollection.collection.collectionId = :collectionId AND labelCollection.label.labelId = :labelId"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelCollection.RETRIEVE_LABEL_COLLECTION_COPY_PRICES_POLLAS, query = "select lb from LabelCollection lb join lb.label.seasonList ls where lb.collection.collectionId = :colId and ls.seasonId = :seasonDestiny and exists ("
                + " select 1 from CollectionAssignement ca where ca.collection.collectionId = lb.collection.collectionId "
                + " and ca.supplier.labelSupplierId in :idSuppliersToCopy and ca.season.seasonId = :seasonOrigin )")
})

public class LabelCollection extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2948530882980344938L;

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION = "retrieveBySeasonCollection";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION_LABEL_CODE. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION_LABEL_CODE = "retrieveBySeasonCollectionLabelCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_CODE. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_CODE = "retrieveByCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_SAMPLE_LABELS_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_SAMPLE_LABELS_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION = "retrieveSampleLabelsBySeasonCollection";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_SAMPLE_LABELS_BY_SEASON_COLLECTION. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_LABEL_COLLECTION_COPY_PRICES_POLLAS = "retrieveLabelCollectionPrices";

    /** The label collection id. */
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "LABEL_COLLECTION_ID_S", sequenceName = "BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "LABEL_COLLECTION_ID_S", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long labelCollectionId;

    /** The sample. */
    @Column(name = "SAMPLE")
    @EditableField
    private Boolean sample;

    /** The active. */
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private Long active;

    /** The collection. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTION_ID")
    private Collection collection;

    /** The comments. */
    @Column(length = 4000)
    @EditableField
    private String comments;

    /** The file supplier. */
    @Column(name = "FILE_SUPPLIER")
    private byte[] fileSupplier;

    /** The file supplier content type. */
    @Column(name = "FILE_SUPPLIER_CONTENT_TYPE", length = 25)
    private String fileSupplierContentType;

    /** The label. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LABEL_ID")
    private Label label;

    /** The related label collection. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RELATED_LABEL_COLLECTION_ID")
    private LabelCollection relatedLabelCollection;

    /** The related season. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RELATED_SEASON_ID")
    private ActivatableSeason relatedSeason;



//@formatter:off.
/**
 * <ol>Este objeto permite vinvular un precio {@link Price} a: <br/>
 * <li> coleccion {@link Collection}</li>
 * <li> proveedor{@link LabelSupplier}</li>
 * <li> temporada {@link ActivatableSeason}</li>
 * </ol>
 *  Contiene el mapeo de la siguiente entidad: <br/>
 *  
 *   gpe_collection_assignements
 *   Nombre                    Nulo     Tipo <br/>         
 *  ------------------------- -------- ------------<br/>  
 *  <b>COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID NOT NULL NUMBER      </b> <br/>
 *  COLLECTION_ID                      NUMBER       <br/>
 *  SUPPLIER_ID                        NUMBER       <br/>
 *  SEASON_ID                          NUMBER       <br/>
 *  ASSIGNEMENT_DATE                   DATE         <br/>
 *  CREATION_MODE                      VARCHAR2(30) <br/>
 *  CREATED_BY                NOT NULL NUMBER       <br/>
 *  CREATION_DATE             NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) <br/>
 *  LAST_UPDATED_BY           NOT NULL NUMBER       <br/>
 *  LAST_UPDATE_DATE          NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) <br/>
 *  SAMPLE_DEADLINE                    DATE         <br/>
 *  PROPOSAL_DEADLINE                  DATE         <br/>
 *  STATUS                             VARCHAR2(60) <br/>
 *  NOTIFIED                           NUMBER(1)    <br/>
 * 
 * Los atributos que no se encuentran en esta entidad = > {@link BaseEntity} -->
 * atributos de auditoria.
 */
//@formatter:on.
@NamedQueries({

    @NamedQuery(name = CollectionAssignement.RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER, query = "SELECT ca from CollectionAssignement ca WHERE ca.supplier.labelSupplierId =:labelSupplierId") })

@Entity
@Table(name = "GPE_COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENTS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID_S", sequenceName = "GPE_COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_S", allocationSize = 1)
public class CollectionAssignement extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /** Generated serial version id. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7140950871330380100L;

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER = "retrieveBySupplier";

    /** The collection assignement id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID_S", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID")
    private Long collectionAssignementId;

    /** The collection. */
    @EditableField
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTION_ID")
    private Collection collection;

    /** The supplier. */
    @EditableField
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SUPPLIER_ID")
    private LabelSupplier supplier;

    /** The season. */
    @EditableField
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEASON_ID")
    private ActivatableSeason season;


    /** The price list. */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Price> priceList;

    /** The sample deadline. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "SAMPLE_DEADLINE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date sampleDeadline;

    /** The proposal deadline. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "PROPOSAL_DEADLINE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date proposalDeadline;

    /** The assignement date. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "ASSIGNEMENT_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date assignementDate;

    /** The creation mode. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "CREATION_MODE")
    private String creationMode;

    /** The status. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    /** The notified. */
    @EditableField
    @Column(name = "NOTIFIED")
    private Boolean notified;

    /** The development list. */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignement")
    private List<Development> developmentList;


//@formatter:off
/**
 * 
 * Contiene el mapeo de la siguiente entidad: <br/>
 * PRD_OWNER.BET_LABELS <br/>
 * Nombre              Nulo     Tipo     <br/>      
 *------------------- -------- -------------- <br/>
 * <b>LABEL_ID            NOT NULL NUMBER     </b>    <br/>
 * VERSION                      NUMBER         <br/>
 * REFERENCIA          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)   <br/>
 * ACTIVA              NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * ETI_PVP                      NUMBER         <br/>
 * ETI_CAL_CCO                  NUMBER         <br/>
 * LEYENDA_ESP                  VARCHAR2(4000) <br/>
 * LEYENDA_ENG                  VARCHAR2(4000) <br/>
 * TIPO_LABEL_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * RELATED_LABEL_ID             NUMBER         <br/>
 * FORMATO_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * AMBITO_ID           NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * MANGO_MNG_LK_ID              NUMBER         <br/>
 * CREATED_BY          NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * CREATION_DATE       NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)   <br/>
 * LAST_UPDATED_BY     NOT NULL NUMBER         <br/>
 * LAST_UPDATE_DATE    NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)   <br/>
 * IMAGE                        BLOB           <br/>
 * INTERIOR_EXTERIOR            VARCHAR2(30)   <br/>
 * EXPORTED                     NUMBER(6)      <br/>
 * TOBE_EXPORTED                NUMBER(6)      <br/>
 * SAP_EXPORT_STATUS            NUMBER(6)      <br/>
 * LAST_SAP_EXPORT_TRY          TIMESTAMP(6)   <br/>
 * 
 *  Los atibutos de la entidad relacionados con auditoria se encuentran en la entidad heredada --> {@link BaseEntity}
 *
 */
//@formatter:on.



 @Entity

    @Table(name = "BET_LABELS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "LABELS_ID_S", sequenceName = "BET_LABELS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)

public class Label extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

/** Generated serial version id. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5428182745695196613L;

/** The label id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "LABELS_ID_S", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "LABEL_ID", nullable = false)
private Long labelId;

/** The activa. */
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long activa;

/** The exported. */
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long exported;

/** The tobe exported. */
@Column(name = "TOBE_EXPORTED", nullable = false)
private Long tobeExported;

/** The eti cal cco. */
@Column(name = "ETI_CAL_CCO")
private Long etiCalCco;

/** The eti pvp. */
@Column(name = "ETI_PVP")
private Long etiPvp;

/** The leyenda eng. */
@Column(name = "LEYENDA_ENG", length = 4000)
private String leyendaEng;

/** The leyenda esp. */
@Column(name = "LEYENDA_ESP", length = 4000)
private String leyendaEsp;

/** The referencia. */
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
private String referencia;

/** The version. */
@Version
private Long version;

/** The int ext. */
@Column(name = "INTERIOR_EXTERIOR")
private String int_ext;

// XXX Lazy fetching does not work in this context according to
/** The image. */
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112508/basicfetch-fetchtype-lazy-does-not-work
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "IMAGE")
private byte[] image;

// Linkado a las tablas de MNG_OWNER

/** The mango mng lk id. */
@Column(name = "MANGO_MNG_LK_ID", nullable = true)
private Long mangoMngLkId;

// Relaciones

/** The season list. */
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "BET_LABEL_SEASONS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LABEL_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEASON_ID") })
private List<ActivatableSeason> seasonList;

/** The format. */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FORMATO_ID")
private LabelFormat format;

/** The kind of label. */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TIPO_LABEL_ID")
private KindOfLabel kindOfLabel;



//@formatter:off
/**
 * Contiene el mapeo de la siguiente entidad: <br/>
 * PRD_OWNER.GPE_LABEL_SUPPLIERS <br/>
 *Nombre            Nulo     Tipo     <br/>            
 *----------------- -------- -------------------<br/> 
 *<b>LABEL_SUPPLIER_ID NOT NULL NUMBER </b>             <br/>
 *CREDITOR_ID                NUMBER              <br/>
 *NAME              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)  <br/>
 *COMMENTS                   VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) <br/>
 *CODE                       VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *TERRITORY_CODE             VARCHAR2(2)         <br/>
 *CREATED_BY        NOT NULL NUMBER              <br/>
 *CREATION_DATE     NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)        <br/>
 *LAST_UPDATED_BY   NOT NULL NUMBER              <br/>
 *LAST_UPDATE_DATE  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)        <br/>
 *STATUS                     VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *TECHNICAL_DETAILS          VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *ETHIC_CODE                 VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *CONTRACT                   VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *TYPE                       VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *LABEL_TYPE                 VARCHAR2(30)        <br/>
 *SUPPLIER_TYPE              VARCHAR2(30) <br/>
 *
 * Los atributos de la entidad relacionados con auditoria se encuentran en la entidad heredada --> {@link BaseEntity}
 */
//@formatter:on.
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_BY_NAME_QUERY, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier WHERE supplier.name = :name"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier INNER JOIN supplier.seasonList season WHERE season.seasonId = :seasonId AND supplier.territory.territoryCode = :territoryCode ORDER BY supplier.name ASC"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON_MULTIPLE_TERRITORI, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier INNER JOIN supplier.seasonList season WHERE season.seasonId = :seasonId AND supplier.territory.territoryCode IN :territoryCode ORDER BY supplier.name ASC"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_MISSING_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier INNER JOIN supplier.seasonList season WHERE season.seasonId = :seasonId AND supplier.territory.territoryCode = :territoryCode and supplier.labelSupplierId not in :supplierIds ORDER BY supplier.name ASC") ,
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_RELALTED_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier INNER JOIN supplier.seasonList season WHERE season.seasonId = :seasonId AND supplier.territory.territoryCode = :territoryCode and supplier.labelSupplierId in :supplierIds ORDER BY supplier.name ASC") ,
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER_CODE, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier WHERE supplier.creditor.user.userId = :code"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier ORDER BY supplier.name ASC"),
                @NamedQuery(name = LabelSupplier.RETRIEVE_LIKE_NAME_QUERY, query = "SELECT supplier FROM LabelSupplier supplier WHERE UPPER(supplier.name) LIKE UPPER(:name)")})


 @Table(name = "GPE_LABEL_SUPPLIERS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "GPE_LABEL_SUPPLIER_ID_S", sequenceName = "GPE_LABEL_SUPPLIERS_S", allocationSize = 1)
public class LabelSupplier extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {


    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6967594085491181944L;

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_NAME_QUERY. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_NAME_QUERY = "retrieveByNameQuery";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON = "retrieveActiveSuppliersByTerritoryCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_MISSING_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_MISSING_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON = "retrieveMissingActiveSuppliersByTerritoryCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_RELALTED_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_RELALTED_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON = "retrieveRelatedActiveSuppliersByTerritoryCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON_MULTIPLE_TERRITORI. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS_BY_TERRITORY_CODE_SEASON_MULTIPLE_TERRITORI = "retrieveMissingActiveSuppliersByMultipleTerritoryCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER_CODE. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_BY_SUPPLIER_CODE = "retrieveBySupplierCode";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_ACTIVE_SUPPLIERS = "retrieveActiveSuppliers";

    /** The Constant RETRIEVE_LIKE_NAME_QUERY. */
    public static final String RETRIEVE_LIKE_NAME_QUERY = "retrieveLikeNameQuery";


    /** The label supplier id. */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LABEL_SUPPLIER_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "GPE_LABEL_SUPPLIER_ID_S", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long labelSupplierId;

    /** The code. */
    @Column(unique = true, length = 30)
    private String code;

    /** The comments. */
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String comments;

    /** The contract. */
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String contract;

    /** The ethic code. */
    @Column(name = "ETHIC_CODE", length = 30)
    private String ethicCode;

    /** The label type. */
    @Column(name = "LABEL_TYPE", length = 30)
    private String labelType;

    /** The name. */
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String name;

    /** The status. */
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String status;

    /** The supplier type. */
    @Column(name = "SUPPLIER_TYPE", length = 30)
    private String supplierType;

    /** The technical details. */
    @Column(name = "TECHNICAL_DETAILS", length = 30)
    private String technicalDetails;

    /** The type. */
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String type;

    /** The creditor. */
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREDITOR_ID")
    private CreditorBet creditor;

    /** The territory. */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TERRITORY_CODE")
    private ActivatableTerritory territory;

    /** The label supplier contact. */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "labelSupplier" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private LabelSupplierContact labelSupplierContact;

    /** The season list. */
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "GPE_SEASONS_SUPPLIERS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LABEL_SUPPLIER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEASON_ID") })
    private List<ActivatableSeason> seasonList;
```

Sql:

```
StringBuilder hastaLosCojones= new StringBuilder(
                " SELECT BLC1.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID, BLC1.ACTIVE, BLC1.COLLECTION_ID, "
                        + "BLC1.COMMENTS, BLC1.FILE_SUPPLIER_CONTENT_TYPE, BLC1.LABEL_ID, BLC1.RELATED_LABEL_COLLECTION_ID, "
                        + "BLC1.RELATED_SEASON_ID, BLC1.SAMPLE "
                        + "FROM BET_LABEL_SEASONS BLS, BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS BLC1 "
                        + "WHERE BLS.LABEL_ID = BLC1.LABEL_ID " + "AND BLC1.COLLECTION_ID = " + idCol + " "
                        + "AND BLS.SEASON_ID = " + seasonDestiny + " " + "AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 "
                        + " FROM GPE_COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENTS GPE, BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS BLC "
                        + " WHERE GPE.COLLECTION_ID  = BLC.COLLECTION_ID "
                        + " AND GPE.COLLECTION_ID = BLC1.COLLECTION_ID " + " AND BLC.LABEL_ID = BLC1.LABEL_ID ");

        hastaLosCojones.append(generadorDeOrs(idSuppliersToCopy, " GPE.SUPPLIER_ID"));
        hastaLosCojones.append(" AND GPE.SEASON_ID = ");
        hastaLosCojones.append(seasonOrigin);
```

JPQL query:

```
    select lb from LabelCollection lb join lb.label.seasonList ls
     where lb.collection.collectionId = :colId and ls.seasonId = :seasonDestiny and exists( select 1 from CollectionAssignement ca 
where ca.collection.collectionId = lb.collection.collectionId 
and ca.supplier.labelSupplierId in :idSuppliersToCopy and ca.season.seasonId = :seasonOrigin)
```

ty.

Comment: since JPQL requires entities and fields and you haven't posted them, how do you expect anyone to comment ?

Comment: apologize me I try to improve my question

Comment: why does a Collection field `LabelCollection.collection` have `@ManyToOne` ?! What SQL is generated by that JPQL? Look in the JPA providers log